# Como alterar el estilo css de varios elementos html individualmente, seleccionando sus id a partir de una misma clase?

Tags: javascript, html, css

SITUACION:
cuando clickeo uno, se alteran los dos..

[image: Al principio estan asi]
[image: despues de clickear]
[image: se altera la opacidad de ambos]

Lo que busco es que al  clickear uno se altere **solo su opacidad** al 100% y viceversa.
y que al clickear de nuevo **también disminuya dicha opacidad** al 50%

**HTML:**

```
        <div class="opcionContacto">
            <img onclick="opacidad()" id="mailWay" class="contactWay" src="/recursos/correos-electronicos.png" alt="">
            <img onclick="opacidad()" id="phoneWay" class="contactWay" src="/recursos/smartphone.png" alt="">
        </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
    /*$ antes de clickear */
.contactWay{
    width: 7%;
    opacity: 50%;
    margin:  3px;
}

/*$ despeues de clickear */
.contactWayClick{opacity: 100%;}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
const clicki = document.querySelectorAll(".contactWay");

const mailId = clicki[0].getAttribute('id');
const phoneId = clicki[1].getAttribute('id');

function opacidad() {
    if (mailId === "mailWay") {clicki[0].classList.toggle("contactWayClick");}
    if (phoneId === "phoneWay") {clicki[1].classList.toggle("contactWayClick");}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No necesitas involucrar IDs, basta obtener todos los elementos y recorrerlos para asignar evento. Dentro de la función del evento analizas cuál recibió clic para cambiar opacidad y restablecer el otro para que solo uno aparezca con opacidad 100%.

```js
// Obtener todos los elementos
let contactWays = document.querySelectorAll('.contactWay');

// Recorrer para asignar evento
contactWays.forEach(cw => cw.addEventListener('click', opacity));

// Recibir evento para identificar elemento
function opacity(e) {
    // Recorrer elementos
    contactWays.forEach(cw => {
        // Si es el que recibió clic
        if(cw == e.currentTarget) {
            // Intercambiar clase
            cw.classList.toggle('contactWayClick');
        } else {
            // Quitar clase, solo se va a mostrar uno con opacidad
            cw.classList.remove('contactWayClick');
        }
    });
}
```

```css
/*$ antes de clickear */
.contactWay{
    width: 7%;
    opacity: 50%;
    margin:  3px;
}

/*$ despeues de clickear */
.contactWayClick{opacity: 100%;}

/* Solo para probar */
.contactWay {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 30px;
}
#mailWay {
    background: #a00;
}
#phoneWay {
    background: #00a;
}
```

```html
<div class="opcionContacto">
    <img id="mailWay" class="contactWay" src="/recursos/correos-electronicos.png" alt="">
    <img id="phoneWay" class="contactWay" src="/recursos/smartphone.png" alt="">
</div>
```